# Separating Aliases in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How do I separate aliases, so I don't touch default ones, and have my own, that I can copy to other machines that I work on? Is there some trick to have one file that you can edit or something? Like a `.bashrc` in Linux. This Import-Export is so... Microsoft. I'm using Powershell 4.0.

Comment: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx) is a technet article about profiles. you can edit ps1 files and copy them between machines. If you use roaming profiles it is easier. Do you want to overwrite the default aliases in powershell?

Comment: No just to add some.

Comment: Then just add your aliases to Profiles. Linked by both me and Alroc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of the `.bashrc` for PowerShell is the [profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx). Any code you want to run or aliases/cmdlets you want to have defined in any PowerShell session should be placed into your profile.

Comment: Looks like we linked the same article.

Comment: Thank you both -). I did not realise that I have to create path\file, I'm so tired...